# Convergence/divergence of improper integrals

Tags: convergence-divergence, indefinite-integrals

I have a task like that and I'm hopeless with that:

Find the **function** so that $$J_0=\int_0^\infty f(x)\,{\rm d}x $$ **converges** and the integrals $$J_1=\int_0^\infty f(x)\sin x \,{\rm d}x,\quad J_2=\int_0^\infty f(x)\sin (x^2)\, {\rm d}x$$ **diverge**.

Does anyone have a clue for searched function? Thank you so much.

Comment: Does $J_2$ have the integrand $f(x)\sin^2(x)$ or the integrand $f(x)\sin( x^2)$?

Comment: @Clayton it's f(x) sin(x^2)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $J_0$ should converge only conditional. The idea is to choose $f$ with the same sign as $\sin x$ or $\sin(x^2)$, so after multiplication it will become positive.

Let $g(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $h(x) = \frac{\sin\left(x^2\right)}{x}$. It's easy to check that $\int_1^\infty g(x)\,\rm dx$ and $\int_1^\infty h(x)\,\rm dx$ converge, and $\int_1^\infty g(x)\sin x\,\rm dx$ and $\int_1^\infty h(x)\sin\left(x^2\right)\,\rm dx$ diverge.

Now, we have three possibilities.

If $\int_1^\infty g(x)\sin\left(x^2\right)\,\rm dx$ diverges, take $f(x) = g(x)$.

If $\int_1^\infty h(x)\sin\left(x\right)\,\rm dx$ diverges, take $f(x) = h(x)$.

If they both converge, take $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$.